# Should I use nginx to rewrite Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, nginx, url-rewriting, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js to develop a website now.

I wrote some pages in the Page Folder.

```
Pages/
  Index.vue
  profile/
     Index.vue
```

Then , When I access

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/
http://www.mywebsite.com/profile
```

will show the Index.vue in Pages/ and profiles/

Now , I need my website using url to define the language of website , like

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/en/   English
http://www.mywebsite.com/ja/profile  Japanese
```

So I use nginx with proxy_pass and rewrite to solve this problem
I use the configs below

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:7777;
rewrite ^/cn/(.*) /$1 last;
```

In developing (run npm dev / nuxt), The site will render the redirected page and turn to blank page with the error immediately . Which is said that the server and client is not sync .

I think the problem is the development mode will auto reload , so the server can detect the url is not same as the pages path.

Then I try to run

```
nuxt build
npm start
```

The site is builded and the redirect is success.

Here is some questions

1) How can I stop the detection when i use "npm dev" ? If I run "npm start" , the page will not be updated anymore even I update the file.

2) I will detect urls language and load different language json file. will this affect Nuxt.js 's Server Side Rendering ?

3) Any other simpler way to solve my problem ? or any nuxt/vue can perform "lang in URL" and let server render all languages' page correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2) and 3), there is actually a much simpler approach, without using nginx

https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n

You can find exact example of what you want to achieve here

https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/routing.html#routing